# iOS app needs votes/flags remaining counts

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, ios-app, close-dialog, flag-dialog

The websites show, in the vote-to-close and flag dialogs, the number of votes or flags remaining. In the iOS app, however, there is no way that I can find to see how many close votes or flags I have remaining for the day.

As a result of this omission, it is easy to rip through them and run out. I like to keep a few votes and flags in reserve for egregiously bad problems (or extremely good posts needing an upvote).

Please add counts for the close votes remaining and flags remaining to the iOS app.