# iPad App voting limit warning notification missing

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ipad

When voting using a web browser you receive a warning message when you are getting close to the daily limit. On each vote from `Daily Limit - 5` a message is shown that `You have X votes left today`.

It's a nice informative message that is very useful if you'd like to continue working with all review queues as an example. I miss this feature on the iPad App. Is it possible to have it implemented on the App too?

Comment: Which kind of voting?

Comment: @BrianNickel Voting on questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks.  There's a [similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257478/ios-app-needs-votes-flags-remaining-counts) around close votes which I will track together.

Comment: @BrianNickel Oh! My question is almost a duplicate of that request. I didn't address the flagging request though. Close as dupe?

Comment: We can keep them separate.